# Use JavaScript to create dynamic Twitter Summary Card is not work

Tags: javascript, twitter

Html like this, in `<head>`:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Title A">
```

And js like this:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:title"]').setAttribute('content', 'Title B');
```

Then, I tweet a twitter with this website.
And it shows the 'Title A'.

Comment: Perhaps Twitter doesn't execute javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping "`:`" (I use jquery)

```
$("meta[name='twitter\\:title']").attr("content", 'Title B');
```

Reference [there](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I think code is right, otherwise it will throw a error `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null`